# erasing/formating/deleting a Usb Flash drive

Tags: usb-drive

I loaded Ubuntu on to flashdrive. Now I want to remove it but when I try it returns `Drive write protected`.
I have tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/devsdb bs=512 count=1`, but that returns `Read only file system`. I have tried many different USB format programs and all say the same. It does not have a switch on it! It is a 32gb CoreMicro USB flash drive. How do I remove Ubuntu from this USB drive?

Comment: You said you used `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/devsdb bs=512 count=1`. Is that a typo in your question, or did you actually run that? (It should be `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` instead, with a `/` between `dev` and `sdb`.) Or was it something else? Also, when the device is plugged in, what's the ouput of `df -h`, `mount`, and `file /dev/sdb`? *Please edit your question to provide all this information.*

Answer (score -1):

then you have really problem on that drive cause They are no chance to unlock it, my friend have this too and i tried everything on it but can't format or everything.

Comment: That is not an answer.